# When different listeners of Nhibernate are notified?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, orm

I want to know when these listeners are notified? I am not getting detailed documentations.

1. DefaultAutoFlushEventListener
2. DefaultPersistEventListener
3. DefaultLoadEventListener
4. DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener
5. DefaultDeleteEventListener
6. DefaultFlushEntityEventListener

Answer (score 1):

From the [NHibernate documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-events)

> 12.2. Event system
>
> If you have to react to particular events in your persistence layer,
>   you may also use the NHibernate2 event architecture. The event system
>   can be used in addition or as a replacement for interceptors.
>
> Essentially all of the methods of the ISession interface correlate to
>   an event. You have a LoadEvent, a FlushEvent, etc (consult the XML
>   configuration-file XSD or the NHibernate.Event namespace for the full
>   list of defined event types). When a request is made of one of these
>   methods, the ISession generates an appropriate event and passes it to
>   the configured event listeners for that type. Out-of-the-box, these
>   listeners implement the same processing in which those methods always
>   resulted. However, you are free to implement a customization of one of
>   the listener interfaces (i.e., the LoadEvent is processed by the
>   registered implemenation of the ILoadEventListener interface), in
>   which case their implementation would be responsible for processing
>   any Load() requests made of the ISession.